# Dask - exclusive resource access?

Tags: dask

Some resources like GPUs or certain data stores are best utilized exclusively, i.e. a single client at a time.

Dask supports selecting a subset of workers by name [1](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/worker.html?highlight=alias#command-line-tool) (aliases) so I can limit GPU work to GPU workers.

In this scenario how would I lock resources? I.e. a given worker should only ever run a single task at a time, even when two separate clients submit work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to handle this today is to create a separate worker with a single thread for each GPU

```
user@host1$ dask-worker scheduler:8786
user@host1$ dask-worker scheduler:8786 --nthreads 1 --name gpu-1

user@host2$ dask-worker scheduler:8786
user@host2$ dask-worker scheduler:8786 --nthreads 1 --name gpu-2

user@host3$ dask-worker scheduler:8786
user@host3$ dask-worker scheduler:8786 --nthreads 1 --name gpu-3
```

And submit some tasks to the entire cluster and other tasks to just those GPU workers

```
>>> gpu_workers = ['gpu-1', 'gpu-2', 'gpu-3']

>>> client = Client('scheduler:8786')

>>> data = client.map(load, filenames)
>>> futures = client.map(process, data, workers=gpu_workers)
```

(see [data locality docs](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/locality.html#user-control) for more ways to submit tasks to certain machines

This is less-than-ideal in a few ways:

1. We'll move data across a process boundary unnecessarily to get to the special GPU-owning process.  Track [dask/distributed #400](https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/400) which should eventually resolve this.
2. You have to maintain a list of gpu-workers yourself.  Track [dask/distributed #505](https://github.com/dask/distributed/pull/505) which should resolve this